# TImeout or error handling for hung Excel VBA code on failed image download

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel VBA code which downloads pictures from a web site.

If the web-host does not start or complete providing the image, then the code hangs indefinitely displaying the "downloading" user dialogue box. You can  click on "cancel" but then you need to restart Excel rather than gracefully resuming the code.

How can I resume gracefully when the "display box" is displayed?

How can I time out if the download did not complete in 10 seconds?  Or, how can I more gracefully handle the user clicking cancel on the download box?

The code snippets I tried were different use cases which I could not re-purpose.

The download box hangs occasionally on the code line `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select`

```
Dim xRg As Range
Dim productphoto As shape
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:I2")
For Each cell In Rng
   filenam = cell

   ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select

    Set productphoto = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    If productphoto Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
            Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column)
    With productphoto
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 100
        .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
        .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
    End With   
lab:
Set productphoto = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("C2").Select
Next
```